# Prevent golang http.NewRequest from adding braces to POST body

Tags: go

This must be fairly simple, but I can't work out why, when making an HTTP request with go, the body of the request gets wrapped in an additional set of braces:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    jsonStr := []byte(`{"some":"test","json":"data"}`)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://test.com", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    fmt.Print(req.Body)
}
```

This results in:

```
{{"some":"test","json":"data"}}
```

In my actual code I'm using the json.Marshal and a struct to generate the byte buffer, but getting the same result. The result is the API rejecting the request (as expected).

How do I prevent the extra braces being added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The printed representation of the body is not the same as the contents of the reader. The http.NewRequest function does not add braces to POST body.

Here's what's going on:

The body is a [ioutil.nopCloser](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/504deee6088c2448fc3e91c94a1ba69ec92fb7ef/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L107-L117) with the Reader field set to the `*bytes.Buffer`.

The `fmt.Print` function prints the `ioutil.nopCloser` struct as `{` + fields + `}`. This is the extra set of braces in the printed output. The fmt.Print function prints the `Reader`  field by calling the `*bytes.Buffer.String` method. The `String` method returns the contents as a string.

The body is sent by reading it, not by printing it.